# Как прочитать заранее заданную строку?

Tags: c++, linux, строки

Как на C++ прочитать не весь файл, не первые n-строк, а конкретную строку по её номеру и вывести именно данную строку в переменную для дальнейшего использования. В интернете находил инфу только про обычное построчное чтение из файла. Считать первые n-строк - додумался и сам:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string lts;
    ifstream txtfile;
    txtfile.open("file.txt");
    unsigned int a = 0;
    while(getline(txtfile, lts)) {
        cout << lts << endl;
        a += 1;
        if (a==255) { //допустим, надо считать строго 255 строк
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Можно, конечно, так же считать и n-нную строку, но читать ещё кучу строк перед ней - это, как по мне, неграмотная трата ресурсов системы. **Есть ли способы считывания строки по заранее известному её порядку?** *Используемая система - Linux/Unix*

Comment: можно, конечно, вывести все строки в массив строк (да и я хз, как это сделать), но все равно получается неграмотная трата ресурсов...

Comment: Если файл всё время один и тот же - один раз постройте индекс - номера строк, позиции, длины. Потом достаточно будет считать кусочек нужной длины из нужного места. Иначе  - увы, придётся читать построчно

Comment: Если длины строк заранее известны, то можно вычислить и установить необходимую позицию курсора чтения (seekg).

Comment: в моём случае, длины строк как раз заранее известны с конца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, конечно вы не можете сразу перейти к какой то строке, но вы можете  просто пропустить все предыдущие символы _ читать и выкинуть, а не запоминать строки в какой то объект:

```
//a = 255
const unsigned    max = -1;
//просто большое число
//чтобы точно добраться до конца строки    
while(txtfile && --a) {
    txtfile.ignore(max, '\n'); 
}      
getline(txtfile, lts);  
//теперь мы прочли в lts только а_тую строку
```

Comment: Зачем копировать то, что ОС сама делает уже? (`man mmap()`)

Answer (score 5):

Как прочитать строку с заданным номером (`n`) из текстового файла? Есть два способа: последовательное чтение `n` строк (мы решили что это расточительно) и установка позиции файлового указателя на начало нужной строки. Чтобы установить надо знать где строка начинается. Где начинается строка `n`? Сразу после окончания строки `n - 1`. Чтобы найти это окончание нужно знать начало строки `n - 1` и все её символы. Формат текстового файла не позволяет найти конец строки не прочитав её всю. Единственная строка начало которой известно точно - первая строка. Круг замкнулся, чтобы прочитать строку `n` нужно прочитать весь текст до неё (а мы решили что это расточительно).

*Из комментариев:* если файл один, а запросов на чтение произвольных строк много, то можно составить индекс: начала строк по их номерам. Чтобы составить индекс, надо прочитать весь файл целиком.

Вернулись откуда начали: формат текстового файла не позволяет произвольный доступ по номеру сроки.

1. Смиритесь, или
2. постройте дополнительную поисковую структуру, или
3. используйте другой формат.

**P.S.** Тот же факт доказывается строго для детерминированной программы. Пусть вы узнали что строка `n` начинается с позиции `p`. Пусть вы ухитрились узнать это не прочитав символ на позиции `q` (`q < p`). Тогда я беру этот файл и заменяю символ `q` на перевод строки (если он не был переводом) или на пробел (если он был переводом строки). Ещё раз запустите программу. Она снова вернёт `p` - она не читает символ на позиции `q` и не может изменить свой ответ. Но ответ перестал быть верным. Вывод: или программа читает все символы, или ошибается.